# How to pass a variable to a slot in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component

I'm just getting started with slots and would like to pass variables to the slot without using stores (e.g. colors, active state, etc), but I can't get it to work, despite having read the tutorial several times.

I've made a REPL to illustrate: [Passing variables to slots](https://svelte.dev/repl/cb9c1963652d40e19e13f87a235da53e?version=3.58.0).

Ideally, I would like to set the variable from the outer component (i.e. "#f00"), but having it set by the component with the slot would be okay as well (i.e. "#0f0").

Thank you in advance!

**Edit:** Source:

```html
<!-- Icon.svelte -->
<script>
  export let fillColor = "#00f";
</script>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" height=24 width=24
  ><path
    d="M14.12 10.47L12 12.59l-2.13-2.12-1.41 1.41L10.60 14l-2.12 2.12 1.41 1.41L12 15.41l2.12 2.13 1.41-1.41L13.41 14l2.12-2.12zM15.5 4l-1-1h-5l-1 1H5v2h14V4zM6 19c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V7H6v12zM8 9h8v10H8V9z" fill={fillColor}/></svg>
```

```html
<!-- IconWrapper.svelte -->
<script>
  export let fillColor = '#0f0';
</script>

<div>
  <slot fill={fillColor}/>
</div>
```

```html
<!-- App.svelte -->
<script>
    import IconWrapper from "./IconWrapper.svelte"
    import Icon from "./Icon.svelte"
    export let fillColor = '#f00';
</script>

<IconWrapper {fillColor}>
  <Icon></Icon>
</IconWrapper>
```

Comment: Please add code to the question instead of linking to an external site, this will ensure that at a later time other visitors can always see the code in case the repl goes down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there, I would suggest to mix up names though because if everything is called the same it might get confusing.

The `IconWrapper` and `Icon` components are ok (renamed fillColor to fill in one place here)

```html
<-- IconWrapper.svelte -->
<script>
  export let fillColor = '#0f0';
</script>

<div>
  <slot fill={fillColor}/>
</div>
```

```html
<!-- Icon.svelte -->
<script>
  export let fillColor = "#00f";
</script>
{fillColor}
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" height=24 width=24
  ><path
    d="M14.12 10.47L12 12.59l-2.13-2.12-1.41 1.41L10.60 14l-2.12 2.12 1.41 1.41L12 15.41l2.12 2.13 1.41-1.41L13.41 14l2.12-2.12zM15.5 4l-1-1h-5l-1 1H5v2h14V4zM6 19c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V7H6v12zM8 9h8v10H8V9z" fill={fillColor}/></svg>
```

Now you can use the `let:` syntax to get a value from the component providing the slot to the component using the slot, you do this by putting `let:` *on the component itself*, this variable will then be defined within the scope of that component.

```html
<!-- App.svelte -->
<script>
  import IconWrapper from "./IconWrapper.svelte"
  import Icon from "./Icon.svelte"
  const fillColor = '#f00';
</script>

<IconWrapper {fillColor} let:fill>
  <Icon fillColor={fill}></Icon>
</IconWrapper>
```

As you see here, I pass `fillColor` to the wrapper, which gives me `fill` back, that is then passed to `Icon`.